# Sample a dataframe with the seq function

Tags: r

How do I shorten my dataframe with 400 rows, to the first 100 observations in the dataset with the seq function?

```
testdataframe = data.frame(animals, status)

testdataframe
```

This would print out all 400.

I know I can do this and get the first 100:

```
head(testdataframe, 100)
```

but I would also like to know how to use the seq function to do this.

Comment: Why? `head` is the easiest way to get the first 100 rows

Comment: data.frame[1:100, ] or data.frame[seq(100), ] if you really want to use seq.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
testdataframe[seq(from=1,to=100),]
```

but nobody would ever do this. The most common approach is to use plain indexing:

```
testdataframe[1:100,]
```

This [link](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-frame-row-slice) might help you to understand indexing dataframes in R: